# Condition an inner join

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements

I have a DB built as following:
Inactive Table - including all deleted\Inactive users
Active Table - including all currently active users
Main Table - including all users (both active and inactive)

some fields exists in all three tables (Such as userName), and I would like to take the data from the Inactive or Active table (Since the data is not always equal in all of the tables), so I want to have a join which will be either from the Active table or Inactive table (according to ActiveState field in the main table)

My query is quite complicated, but to simplify it, I have a small example which explains my problem:

```
SELECT M.ID,
       A.userName
FROM   MainTbl M

IF M.ActiveState = 'Active'
   THEN 
   INNER JOIN ActiveTbl A ON A.UserID = M.ID
ELSE
    INNER JOIN InactiveTbl A ON A.UserID = M.ID
END
    INNER JOIN SomeTbl S ON S.Field = A.Field
```

***Note:*** *For both tables I used A, the reason is that I use this table for the select itself and to some more inner joins*

Is there any way to do so?

Thanks

Comment: Since a user cannot be active and inactive at the same time, why not join main table with both tables, and union them.

Comment: There's no way you'll be allowed to give the same alias (`A`) to both `ActiveTbl` and `InactiveTbl`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN and then something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN A.ID IS NULL 
            THEN I.userName
            ELSE ActiveTbl.userName 
       END AS userName
FROM   MainTbl M
       LEFT JOIN ActiveTbl A 
                 ON A.UserID = M.ID 
                 AND m.ActiveState = 'Active'
       LEFT JOIN InactiveTbl I
                 ON I.UserID = M.ID
```

Comment: But it should be the same letter...
My query is much more complicated than what I gave as an example there... 

I have more inner joins that should be with one of those tables (after the END you can see there is an inner join to "SomeTbl" through A, which could be either Active or Inactive table)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE M.ActiveState
            WHEN 'Active' THEN A.userName
            ELSE I.userName
       END AS userName
FROM   MainTbl M
       LEFT JOIN ActiveTbl A
            ON  A.UserID = M.ID
       LEFT JOIN InactiveTbl I
            ON  I.UserID = M.ID
```